# MySQL connections from PHP on IIS?

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I have inherited a web site that is in PHP and we are mostly a Windows shop. I cannot get the PHP code to connect to MySQL at all.

1 - The IDE is Eclipse. I imported the project and set up a debug configuration and everything works fine there with HTML and other PHP (non DB) code.

2 - I am running IIS 7.5 with PHP enabled

3 - I have tried to connect to two completely separate MySQL instances (different hosts, different DBs, etc) and it will not connect

I have already made sure that sql.safemode is turned to OFF and there is no default server in php.ini (that shouldn't come into play if safe mode is OFF, right?)

I have done nothing special to the PHP code or project and I'm wondering if that's part of the issue - do I need a JAR or reference of any kind to enable the MySQL connections?

The PHP code is as follow - nothing special I think:

```
$db_name = "foo";
$connection = @mysql_connect("myserver", "myuser", "mypw") or die("Could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die("Count not select database");
```

the above code always results in the die statement of "Could not connect to database"

Comment: What error do you get if you remove the error suppression from the `mysql_connect` statement?

Comment: Basic debugging: Remove the `@` to stop actively suppressing errors, and stick `mysql_error()` into those `die()` calls to see what is actually going wrong.

Comment: Again, keep in mind that I'm not a PHP guy. So mysql_error is still an improvement for me :) This resulted in: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Answer (score 0):

The @ symbol is not necessary for making a DB connection, as far as I know.

Try

> $connection = mysql_connect("myserver", "myuser", "mypw") or die("Could not connect to database");

Comment: You're right that it's not necessary (and almost always a bad idea) but `@` has nothing to do with the specific functionality used in this context. The error suppressor can be applied to any function or context.

Comment: @-symbol is used for hiding errors, remove it as sugested above, and tell us what error its hiding

Comment: This resulted in: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. Keep in mind that I tried multiple MySQL servers so it still must be something with my PHP configuration

Comment: Have you double checked to make sure the connection credentials are correct? Ie. "myserver", "myuser", "mypw" are the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

First need to load php.ini file.
How to load php.ini file

1. Rename any one of the file php.ini-production/php.ini-development to php.ini from C:\PHP(note now the extention will be ini i.e "php.ini").
2. After renaming to php.ini file restart server .Open a text editor, for example Notepad, as Administrator.
3. In a new file, type the following text:`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
4. Save the file as C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Phpinfo.php.
5. Open a browser and enter the following URL:
   http://localhost/phpinfo.php

[image]

#### How to Enable mysqli in php.ini

Edit php.ini by uncommenting (removing ';') the following config-lines:

```
// 1st (uncomment and add config): 
include_path = "C:\php\includes"

// <2nd (uncomment): 
extension_dir = "ext"

// 3rd (uncomment and edit config): 
extension=C:/PHP/ext/php_mysql.dll
extension=C:/PHP/ext/php_mysqli.dll
```

After editing restart the IIS server and make sure that mysql is running on the system.

Make changes in the code i.e  phpinfo.php file to see DB connectivity

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

[image]